# Scala getResourceAsStream() fails silently while loading keystore

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, getresource

I'm trying to use getResourceAsStream to load a java keystore albeit unsuccessfully. I'm not sure why it fails, but I'm loading it inside Play! 2.0 from a subfolder inside a typical folder.

Here's the folder structure and keystore location:

**play root >> app >> subfolder1 >> keystore**

And the location of the file I'm loading it from:

**play root >> app >> subfolder1 >> scala.class**

And how I am loading it inside `scala.class`:

`getClass().getResourceAsStream("/keystore")`

Any ideas as to what's going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By prefacing the path with `/` you're asking for a `keystore` at the root of the package hierarchy. Try either of the following:

```
getClass.getResourceAsStream("/app/subfolder1/keystore")
getClass.getResourceAsStream("keystore")
```

See [the Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html) for more detail on how to specify resource paths.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! After some further fiddling I got it to also work by using `/keystore` and placing the keystore file in the conf folder (for those who need a Play 2.0 specific answer)